# Structure of Automorphism group of abelian group $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \times \mathbb{Z}_p \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, automorphism-group

It is well-known that if $G$ be an elementary abelian group of order $p^n$, then $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\cong $  GL($n,p$) (linear group of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Z}_p)$.

My question is about the automorphism group of  $G = \mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \times \mathbb{Z}_p \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_p$. There exist a number of articles from which the order of $|\mathrm{Aut}(G)|$  can be easily obtained( [Theorem 3.2](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00013-005-1547-z)  ).

> I want to know if anyone knows any references that stuy or contain any information about the **exact structure** or **exact form of elements** of **$\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \times \mathbb{Z}_p \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_p)$**?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I understand what you are saying, you mean $\Omega_1(G)$ by $E$, which is a characteristic subgroup of $G$, but is the automorphism group of $G/E$  helps finding the exact form of elements of $\mathrm{Aut}(G)$? Would you please explain it on $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \times \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$ as an example?